# Can I read the bytes transmitted over the CAN-bus on the transmitting side?

Tags: can-bus

Sorry for my question (and my English too). I am a newbie in CAN-bus. I have theoretical question. If I pass any data to one CAN-socket, will I be able to read the same data from the same socket?. After all, the transmitted data appears not only on other nodes of the CAN-bus, but also on the one from which they were transmitted?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. There is no sender and receiver, just nodes. Any node is capable of both reading and writing to the bus.

Comment: Yeah, I know about nodes. Maybe the question is stupid. But I meant that if, at some point in time, a node transmits data, and then immediately reads, then it will read the same data as it transmitted or not?

Comment: It's not a stupid question -- I understand now.  I'm not an expert but I would assume in normal operation that whichever node is transmitting does not see it's own messages.

Comment: A message is not sent until it gets acknowledged(ACK). The transmitter will keep retrying to send until it gets acknowledged successfully.

Comment: You might want to tag this with whatever language and system you are using, to get attention from the people who can answer. There are no sockets in CAN, but there are socket libs for using CAN from Linux - either in C or Python, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I understand. I wrote a small program in C and it turned out that after *successfully* (it's important!) sending the data to the socket corresponding to the CAN interface, you can immediately read back the same data transmitted to the CAN bus. Perhaps this is how the CAN driver is implemented on Linux (can4linux).

Moreover, in order to be able to read the sent data back, it is important that the CAN interface is not alone in the network, since the transmitter node sets the ACK bit value in the transmitted frame to a recessive state and listens to its own transmission, waiting for all receiving nodes to set the ACK confirmation bit in the dominant state in this transmitted frame, which means that there is no error. When listening to its transmission reveals that the ACK bit is in the dominant state (meaning the transmission was successful), the transmitted frame is placed by the CAN interface driver in the input buffer and can be read back from the our socket.

If the transmission fails (the ACK bit remains in a recessive state), the CAN controller will attempt to transmit the frame in a loop. In the program, this will look like the `write` function has ended, but when trying to immediately read the data, the program blocks inside the `read` function if the blocking read mode is set.